# Creating a page with wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress

I have a form that collects data about a user's product and then creates a page in WordPress with

```
$my_post = array(
            'post_content'   => "My page content",
            'post_title'     => $product_title,
            'post_name'      => $product_title,
            'post_type'      => 'page',  // must be 'page'  to accept the 'page_template' below
            'page_template'  => "listing.php",
            'post_status'    => "publish"
        );
        $ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        $permalink = get_permalink($ID);
        echo "<br />ID for new page is $ID, Permalink for new page is $permalink";
```

The form data is put into meta variables for the page ID and the listing.php template file pulls it out of there and builds the HTML to display the product page.   This all works fine and I can see that the page meta variable, _wp_page_template, gets set correctly to the template file I specified,  listing.php:

[image]

Now I want to create a second page from the same form data, this one displaying different parts of the data in a different way.  So I've added a second block of code, starting at $my_cert below,  that creates this second page and specifies a different template, certificate.php, that knows how to build the second version of the data.

```
$my_post = array(
            'post_content'   => "My page content",
            'post_title'     => $product_title,
            'post_name'      => $product_title,
            'post_type'      => 'page',  // must be 'page'  to accept the 'page_template' below
            'page_template'  => "listing.php",
            'post_status'    => "publish"
        );
        $ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        $permalink = get_permalink($ID);
        echo "<br />ID for new page is $ID, Permalink for new page is $permalink";

    $my_cert = array(
      'post_content'   => "My certificate",  // post_content is required
      'post_title'     => "My certificate",  // post_title is required
      'post_name'        => "My certificate",
      'post_type'      => 'page',  // must be 'page'  to accept the 'page_template' below
      'page_template'  => "certificate.php",
      'post_status'    => "publish"
    );
    $CERT_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_cert );
    $cert_permalink = get_permalink($CERT_ID);
    echo "<br />ID for new certificate is $CERT_ID, Permalink for new certificate is $cert_permalink";
```

But when I look in the meta data for the second  page created, the template is set to "default" instead of certificate.php:

[image]

I know I've set up certificate.php correctly as a template (set /*  Template Name:  certificate    */ at the top)  because the Page Edit Template dropdown includes certificate:

[image]

So does anyone see why I can't create this second page with the template set to certificate.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your page template src for: certificate.php is: `certificate.php`? And not: `templates/certificate.php` or something like that. Look in your theme folder and be 100% of the page template path. Check your spelling or for typos in the page template path or name. It must be an exact match.

If you still have problems I would look into and debug the source code of: `wp_insert_post()`

```
if ( ! empty( $postarr['page_template'] ) && 'page' == $data['post_type'] ) {
    $post->page_template = $postarr['page_template'];
    $page_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates( $post );
    if ( 'default' != $postarr['page_template'] && ! isset( $page_templates[ $postarr['page_template'] ] ) ) {
        if ( $wp_error ) {
            return new WP_Error('invalid_page_template', __('The page template is invalid.'));
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', 'default' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', $postarr['page_template'] );
    }
}
```

So its probably this part that fails:

```
if ( 'default' != $postarr['page_template'] && ! isset( $page_templates[ $postarr['page_template'] ] ) )
```

Try to modify: `wp-includes/post.php` and go to the definition of: `function wp_insert_post()` on row: 2872. And add a new row on row: 3312 for debugging purposes.

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $page_templates );
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

Make sure your `certificate.php` is among those in that array. Remember to delete the debug code before continuing. This should give you some answers.

Comment: Yes, you nailed it!  While listing.php was directly under the theme, I put certificate.php in a certificate folder under the theme, so it needed to be certificate/certificate.php.    Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of help!